# SQLite in Python: Getting error Invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python

Can someone help us with this code? We are struggling a bit with the sql-statements and closed databases etc.

We got this error:

```
File "/Users/"our path"/avgrssitable.py", line 35, in avgrssi
avg[0]=query

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "SELECT AVG(rssi) FROM 'unitedata' WHERE dev LIKE dev AND mac LIKE mac AND time<=1515748155 AND time>=1515748125;"
```

Here is our code.
The script sqlfunktion creates a connection to a database and gives the oppurtunity to create and write to tables.

```
import sqlfunktion
from sqlite3 import connect
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime



def avgrssi(date):
    #date on format as "YYYY,mm,dd"
    posconn = sqlfunktion.opendb("totdata")
    uniqmac = posconn.execute("SELECT distinct(mac) FROM unitedata;") 

    avgcon = sqlfunktion.createdb("avgdata")
    avgcon.execute("CREATE TABLE avgrs(time, mac, avg);")

    unixnr=posconn.execute("SELECT MIN(time) FROM 'unitedata';")
    unix= unixnr.fetchone()[0]
    devices=[146, 147, 148, 149]


    for dtime in range(10+int(unix/60), 23*60+int(unix/60)):
        for mac in uniqmac:
            avg = np.array([0,0,0,0])
            for dev in devices:
                query = """SELECT AVG(rssi) FROM 'unitedata' WHERE dev LIKE {} AND mac LIKE {} AND time<={} AND time>={};""".format('dev', 'mac', dtime*60+15, dtime*60-15) 
                #print(query)
                if query != '' and dev==146:
                    avg[0]=query
                elif query !='' and dev==147:
                    avg[1]=query
                elif query !='' and dev==148:
                    avg[2]=query
                elif query !='' and dev==149:
                    avg[3]=query
                else: 
                    print('nej')

                store=[(time, mac, avg)]

            avgcon.executemany("INSERT INTO avgrs(time, mac, avg) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", store.fetchall())
            avgtab = avgcon.executemany("SELECT time, mac, avg FROM avgrs;")  

    close(avgcon)
    return avgtab 

if __name__ == '__main__':


    dato=(2018,1,5)
    avgrssi(dato)

#test=position(2018-01-05)
#print(test.fetchall())
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `unix` value?

Comment: a unix timestamp!

right now it is FLOAT.

Comment: try `float(unix)/60`

Comment: You are trying to set a cell of a np.array with the string `query`. I think you rather want to set it with the result of your `query`.